# Regex to replace double nested quotes in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace double nested quotes from string in C# using Regex, but not able to achieve it so far. Below is the sample text and the code i tried -

```
string html = "<img src=\"imagename=\"g1\"\" alt = \"\">";
string output = string.Empty;
Regex reg = new Regex(@"([^\^,\r\n])""""+(?=[^$,\r\n])", RegexOptions.Multiline); 
output = reg.Replace(html, @"$1");
```

the above gives below output -

```
"<img src="imagename="g1 alt = >"
```

actual output i am looking for is -

```
"<img src="imagename=g1" alt = "">"
```

Please suggest how to correct the above code.

Comment: Be sure you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) before using regex for manipulating html.

Comment: The above string cant be parsed into XML due to the double nested quotes itself, so suggested thread is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern : `\s*"\s*([^ "]+)"\s*(?=[">])|(?<=")("")(?=")`

Replacement : `$1`

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kC6qU7/6) and tested at [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%22%5cs*(%5b%5e+%22%5d%2b)%22%5cs*(%3f%3d%5b%22%3e%5d)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%22)(%22%22)(%3f%3d%22)&i=%3cimg+src%3d%22imagename%3dg1%22+alt+%3d+%22%22%3e%0d%0a%3cimg+src%3d%22imagename%3d%22g1%22%22+alt+%3d+%22%22%22%22%3e%0d%0a%3cimg+src%3d%22imagename%3d%22g1%22%22+alt+%3d+%22%22abc%22%22%3e&r=%241)

String literals for use in programs:

```
@"\s*""\s*([^ ""]+)""\s*(?=["">])|(?<="")("""")(?="")"
```

---

To keep it simple and more precised directly focused for `src` attribute value

Pattern : `(\bsrc="[^ =]+=)"([^ "]+")"`

Replacement : `$1$2`

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kC6qU7/7) and tested at [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cbsrc%3d%22%5b%5e+%3d%5d%2b%3d)%22(%5b%5e+%22%5d%2b%22)%22&i=%3cimg+src%3d%22imagename%3dg1%22+alt+%3d+%22%22%3e%0d%0a%3cimg+src%3d%22imagename%3d%22g1%22%22+alt+%3d+%22%22%3e&r=%241%242)

String literals for use in programs:

```
@"(\bsrc=""[^ =]+=)""([^ ""]+"")"""
```

**Note:** I assume attribute values don't contain any spaces.

Comment: `(=\s*")([^"]*=)"([^"]*")"`, with replacement `$1$2$3` was my refinement of your first regexp, to deal with inner quote containing spaces.  This does not handle `=""abc""` but OP gives little indication that one should.

Comment: @user3218114, giving exactly output i required, thanks a lot!